# How to reach the textproprety of the cell of the table of another view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

The first contains a table that contains some cells.
When user click on a cell the second view is loaded.
In the second view I'd like to retrive the text of the clicked cell in the first view (I have to query a sqlite db with this value).

Thank you

PS:

I call second view through this:

```
void GoToView( UIViewController *from, UIViewController *to){   
    /*
     * Preparo l'animazione e aggiungo la subview.
     */
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:from.view cache:YES];
        [from.view addSubview:to.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you save the value you need in a property of the second view controller?

Comment: Just create a [property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) on the second view controller class and then in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` read that value using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and assign to the view controller property.